# Sitecore item publishing issue

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

Is there any reason the Sitecore item publish did not identify the change, when changing the Camel case to the Pascal case and vice versa?

For example, I have an item with a Description field set to `quarantine`, changed the description field to `Quarantine` save and published it. Sitecore didn't recognize the change.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a known issue with SPS. Depending on what version you're using, this patch may solve your problem: https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.290996

From what I remember, this patch fixes the issue of case changes on fields. If case changes is done on an item `Name`, such change won't be published with the patch either.